# The maps infobox (when an icon is clicked) is not displaying the CSS correctly

Tags: css, web

Ok, So I am making a travel blog through WordPress. I have made some fiddles including maps and some tables which work perfectly in the fiddle. however, now that I put it on my site - it is messing up. I think something to do with the CSS is messing it up - but I cannot find where.

The page I am having the most problem with is located here:

http://www.journeywithandrew.com/world-heritage-sites-reviews-info/

Problem (1): 
The maps infobox (when an icon is clicked) is not displaying the CSS correctly. 
Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4V7en/4/ 
You can see what it is supposed to look like.

Problem (2): 
The fusion layer I imposed is not displaying correctly when using CHROME or iOS browsers. So again, refer to the above fiddle. It displays correctly in the fiddle, and internet explorer - but not chrome. As you can see the layers is distorted in some places on my site. (like if you scroll left on the map over Australia - for example)

Problem (3): 
around my check mark buttons, there seems to be a border on the table I put them in. why!?! I tried to remove this in the table (, etc) but it does not work. Not sure what CSS is causing this!

I think that is all. If someone can take a look at the site and especially using chrome you will be able to see the problems.

```
.caption-title-link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#41a62a;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1 . Add padding: 10em; to .infobox, which replaces the padding:.5em 1em at current. This should make the content sit better.

2 . Dont quite understand the issue

3 . Currently your Td is set to

**border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;**

Remove border-width and replace with border:none

**border: none;**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1.

- Table inside .infobox has a margin-bottom set. Adding `.infobox table { margin-bottom: 0 }` should fix it. Adjusting the td padding inside .infobox is also needed.
- Em values are dependent on font-size, and in your page, you've set the font-size to 1px (vs in Fiddle, where it was 10px). Setting it back to 10px should fix the padding problems.

Problem 2. Which is fusion layer?

Problem 3. Border is coming from style.css, line 412

Comment: No, that didn't work for problem 1, the only variable it is bring in from .infobox is the background and font color. I can change the font-size to 1000px and to 1px - no change. I added your code, but it didn't do anything PROBLEM 2. Fusion layer is located line 119 of the fiddle. It displays correctly on the fiddle, and in internet explorer but not chrome. Scroll to the left on my site and see Australia. See how the overlay is not lining up? it get distorted. This must have something to do with the css. PROBLEM 3, can I somehow asign a class to this table that will override line 412

Comment: Looks like you've been able to fix 1 and 3. I don't have IE right now, so I can't help you with Problem #2.

Comment: yes I have been, since I was defining classes in a table, I had to: table.infobox{} and put the parameter in there. However, I don't understand why jsfiddle lets you get away with only .infobox{} and no table. problem two is driving me crazy. I am sure it has something to do with how chrome and mobile browsers handle the css of my theme. Seems like they are using the same class as the fusion layer or something. And what is really odd is IE doesn't do it. haven't tested other browsers,but ya. May post it on Google forums or just set up a new question here detailing the problem better.